# Amazon mws HTTPS Connection Pool Max tries exceeded with url

Tags: python, amazon-mws

I am using [this](https://github.com/czpython/python-amazon-mws) api to access amazon mws. I want to fetch the Product code attached to a particular Order Id. 

I create a list of 100 order ids and in a for loop try to fetch the Product Codes. But halfway through it gives me an error:

My Code:

```
from mws import mws
auth = mws.Orders(access_key=access_key,secret_key=secret_key,account_id=account_id, region='IN')
oid = []     ###  a list of 100 or so order ids. 
for id in oid:
    item_detail = auth.list_order_items(id)
    item_text = item_detail.original
    file = open('order_details.xml','a')
    file.write(item_text)
    file.close()
```

Error is :

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='mws.amazonservices.in', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /Orders/2013-09-01?AWSAccessKeyId=DWAKIAJDWHSXML4XJT7NVLAQ&Action=ListOrderItems&AmazonOrderId=403-4521860-8323545&SellerId=A3AZIDWDQXFUT4SLU02M7&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2015-06-09T10%3A20%3A45Z&Version=2013-09-01&Signature=IInO1WBi2srQP5q8lTDgTMq%2BvKGrMqCxUqj56/bUYQQ%3D (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

*Access Key & Seller Id changed in Error*

Answer (score 0):

The error thrown is `Max retries exceeded`. So probably you are exceeded the amount of request you can do. It can help to build a sleep-timer in your code (10/100 ms or so, just experiment with it). Another option is to separate your `oid` into different lists, and try it on different moments.

Comment: Is there any other way? Because I tried with a sleep timer of 20 seconds after each request and my requests are still getting throttled. If i increase it more then i will have performance issues for much larger oid list.

Comment: Not that I can think of right now. Does it happen at the same id every time?

Comment: No It is Happening at different Ids. Also I tried to increase the sleep time to 120 secs (I read in mws developer guide that it takes 2 min to replenish the request quota) but no solution. Still getting throttled